# Documentation on the error behavior of @Value

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, annotations

Can any one point me to the Spring documentation that states what will happen when the expression in a @Value annotation

- Throws exception
- Returns null
- Is missing

I need this a written documentation of the behavior to be able to use the annotation confidently.

Thanks.

**Edit:**

The JavaDoc for the annotation only tell you what should happen when the annotation works. There's nothing on error behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only documentation that clearly (depending on how deep you want to go) describes the behaviour is the source code itself. `@Value` annotations are processed by [`AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html).

Let's take one case at a time:

> what will happen when the expression in a @Value annotation
>
> ```
> Throws exception
> ```

For example,

```
public class CustomBean {
    private String value;

    public String getValue() {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

@Component
public class MyComponent {
    private static final String a = "";
    @Value("#{customBean.value}")
    public String value;
}

<context:component-scan base-package="com.spring"></context:component-scan>
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:values.properties"/> 
<bean id="customBean" class="com.spring.CustomBean" >
    <property name="value" value="bomb"></property>
</bean>
```

Spring will try to resolve the `@Value`'s value by calling the `getValue()` getter of the bean of type `CustomBean`. It does this in `org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectivePropertyAccessor$OptimalPropertyAccessor#read(..)` (after going through the SpEL stack to resolve the bean and property name). This method has a `catch (Exception e)` block that will catch any `Exception` and throw an `AccessException` wrapping the caught `Exception`.

> ```
> what will happen when the expression in a @Value annotation
>
> Returns null
> ```

Given this instead

```
public class CustomBean {
    private String value;

    public String getValue() {
        return null;
    }
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

The value of the annotated field will be `null` because that is the value that was resolved and it is valid. If the annotated field is of primitive type, you will get a `NullPointerException` while trying to unwrap it.

> what will happen when the expression in a @Value annotation
>
> ```
> Is missing
> ```

It could be missing in 2 ways. First, if we try to reference a bean's property that doesn't exist. For example,

```
@Value("#{customBean.nonExistent}")
public String value;
```

During the injection process, the SpEL evaluation will fail because the property `nonExistent` cannot be found on the bean's class type. For curious minds, this happens in `org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference#readProperty()`. Spring tries to check any accessor that may be able to resolve it. When it goes through all of them without finding one, it throws an `SpelEvaluationException`.

Second, the property might not exist

```
@Value("${properties.nonExistent}") // note $ vs #
public String value;
```

This can happen if you don't have a property source that contains such a property. A registered `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` (YMMV with other strategy for resolving properties) will go through your `PropertySource` objects and try. If none find a corresponding property, you will get an `IllegalArgumentException` that it could not resolve the placeholder. This happens in `org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper#parseStringValue(..)`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's very thorough. It's a bit sad that it does not warn you when the value is null as it would with bean injection. But at least it throws an exception when the property is not there.

Comment: @billc.cn You're welcome. I'm sure there's a reason for `null` being a valid value. I just don't know it right now.